# Getting a string representation of a SecKey

Tags: swift, public-key-encryption

**Edit** Added a screnshot of the request needed.

I'm trying to make a MacOs app in Swift 4. This app communicates with a api that requires RSA encryption.

Google didn't give results that could explaining how to do this. Apple's documentation on this subject is quite extensive (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/KeyRead.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH222-SW2), but still not what I need.

The function SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation gives a Data object that 
cannot be transformed to a String. The documentation says that it is a PCKS #1 response, but I can't work it out.

I've tried a lot of things, including below, but I can't get it to work.

```
func externalRepresentation(_ key: SecKey) -> String? {
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    guard let data = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(key, &error) as Data? else {
        return nil
    }

    return data.base64EncodedString()
}
```

The request needs to be the following:
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNNvC.png)

Is this even possible in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to encode a binary blob, like a certificate or RSA key as a string is to use [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. You can convert a `Data` to base64 quite easily with the function [`base64EncodedString(options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2142853-base64encodedstring?changes=latest_minor). i.e.

```
let myString = myData.base64EncodedString()
```

<s>whether that is exactly what you need for this application is hard to tell because your question doesn't give much context.</s>

Looking at your screen shot, as well as the base64 encoded string, you need a header and footer. Most of the apparently random letters in the data structure are the base64 string (the JSON conversion has encoded the line feeds with `\n` and something else has doubled up the backslashes). Your last step is therefore to prepend the string with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and a new line, ad append a new line and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

One more thing: you can get the original data back from the base64 string quite easily with [Data.init?((base64Encoded base64String:,options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780388-init?changes=latest_minor). i.e.

```
guard let myDataCopy = Data(base64Encoded: myString)
else { fatalError("the string was not really base64") }
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the question and added a screenshot of the request. As you can see, it needs to be a PCKS #1 string, which isn't a base64 encoded blob, is it?

Comment: @Dastin It is indeed a base64 encoded blob. You have to add the *human readable* prefix and suffix (including the `\n` characters) and you have to pass the option `.lineLength64Characters` to `base64EncodedString(options:)`

Answer (score 1):

SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation returns data in the PKCS #1 format for an RSA key. The RSA Public key PEM file looks like below

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
BASE64 ENCODED DATA
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Within the base64 encoded data the following DER structure is present:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

The PKCS #1 format for an RSA key should be preppended by appropriate “precoded” ASN.1 binary data structure. Refer to the pemPrefixBuffer in the example below:

```
        // creating client public and private key
        var publicKeySec, privateKeySec: SecKey?
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        let keyattribute = [
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 1024,
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false
            ] as CFDictionary
        SecKeyGeneratePair(keyattribute, &publicKeySec, &privateKeySec)
        
        // client public key to pem string
        let keyData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKeySec!, &error)
        let data = keyData! as Data
        let pemPrefixBuffer :[UInt8] = [
            0x30, 0x81, 0x9f, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a,
            0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
            0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x81, 0x8d, 0x00
        ]
        var finalPemData = Data(bytes: pemPrefixBuffer as [UInt8], count: pemPrefixBuffer.count)
        finalPemData.append(data)
        let finalPemString = finalPemData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        let clientPublicKeyString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n\(finalPemString)\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n"
```

Now you can send clientPublicKeyString to your server expecting a PEM encoded RSA Public key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sagar! Can you please refer to any documentation about the prefix buffer?

Comment: @VictorBenetatos Couldn't find much documentation around the prefix buffer. But this is something that worked for me. Would like to know if this solved your problem. If so kindly +1 or mark this as accepted answer :)